# Effect of down-sampling to PSD from auto-correlation?

Tags: discrete-signals, sampling, power-spectral-density, autocorrelation, array-signal-processing

I have a problem to evaluate the PSD from auto-correlation.
As you know, PSD is the Fourier Transform of the auto-correlation.

But I observe the spur at PSD when I calculate the auto-correlation with down-sampled data.

Let me explain my code shown below.

```
import numpy as np

rntau = np.append(rntau, np.mean(phase[:R_size]*phase[:R_size]))
rkntau = np.append(rkntau, np.mean(phase[:R_size*k:k]*phase[:R_size*k:k]))

for tau in range(1, R_size):
    rntau = np.append(rntau, np.mean(phase[:-tau+R_size]*phase[tau:R_size]))
    rkntau = np.append(rkntau, np.mean(phase[:-tau+k*R_size:k]*phase[tau:k*R_size:k]))
```

The array `phase` refers the WSS discrete-time signal $x[n]$. Assuming $x[n]$ is sampled from continuous signal $x(t)$ with sampling $f_s = 6\,\text{GHz}$. It has a peak in the PSD at $100\,\text{MHz}$. And at the other offsets, it has only $1/f^2$ components (by that, I mean the PSD of $x[n]$ has slope of $-20\text{dB}$/dec).

The array `rntau` refers $R[\tau] = \mathbb{E}[x[n]x[n+\tau]]$

and the array `rkntau` refers $R_k[\tau] = \mathbb{E}[x[nk]x[nk+\tau]]$

> $\tau \in 0,1,2,3,\dots$

I thought $R[\tau] = R_k[\tau]$ and the resulted PSD should be the same, but spurs are observed not only at $100\,\text{MHz}$ but also $6N/k\,\text{GHz}$ ($N \in \mathbb{N}$).

I don't know the reason that unexpected spurs are observed.
Would the aliasing not affect PSD because the unit $\tau$ (or step of $\tau$) is constant?

OR if $x[k]$ is not WSS, can the spurs be observed?

**Edited for clarity:**

$$R[\tau=0] = \mathbb{E}[x[n]x[n]]$$

$$R[\tau=1] = \mathbb{E}[x[n]x[n+1]]$$

$$\cdots$$

$$R_k[\tau=0] = \mathbb{E}[x[kn]x[kn]]$$

$$R_k[\tau=1] = \mathbb{E}[x[kn]x[kn+1]]$$

$$\cdots$$

**Edited to share the code computing PSD**

I suppose the sampling frequency is $6GHz$.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f0 = 6e9
fs = fsj = f0
w0 = 2*np.pi*f0
nsamp = len(rntau)
tres = nsamp / fs
ts = np.arange(0, nsamp*1/fs, 1/fs)
win_hann = np.hanning(nsamp)

xfreq_hann1, fft_data_hann1 = positivefft(rntau, fs, win_hann)
xfreq_hann2, fft_data_hann2 = positivefft(rkntau, fs, win_hann)
psd_data_hann1 = (w0)**2 * fft_data_hann1 * tres
psd_data_hann2 = (w0)**2 * fft_data_hann2 * tres

plt.figure(1)
plt.semilogx(xfreq_hann1, 10*np.log10(abs(psd_data_hann1)), 'g', label='rntau', alpha = 0.4)
plt.semilogx(xfreq_hann2, 10*np.log10(abs(psd_data_hann2)), 'r', label='rkntau', alpha = 0.4)
plt.legend(loc='lower left')
plt.grid()
```

And the 'positivefft' is:

```
import numpy as np

def positivefft(x, fs, w=None):
    ts = 1/fs
    nsamp = len(x)

    xfreq = np.fft.rfftfreq(nsamp, ts)[:-1]

    if w is None :
        yfft = (np.fft.rfft(x)/nsamp)[:-1]*2
    else :
        yfft = (np.fft.rfft(x*w)/nsamp)[:-1]*2

    return xfreq, yfft
```

I'm sorry I can't share the array 'phase' because it has too much data and is a dataset in my research.
I recommend testing the code by generating random WSS process. For example:

```
import numpy as np

N = 1000000
h = [1.0, 0.5, 0.25, -0.25]
x = np.random.normal(0.0, 1.0, N)
phase = np.convolve(h, x, mode='valid')
```

All code shared above is written in Python syntax.

cf. I used `2**14` for `R_size`, and `10` for `k`.

The resulted plot (numpy-created WSS process) is shown below: two PSDs are **different** at around $2GHz$.

[image]

And the plot shown below is **Phase-Noise-Case**, I expect that the magnitude at 0Hz is 0dBc/Hz. Spurs are at 600Mhz, 1200MHz, $\cdots$ So I anticipated the spurs are related to k=10 (maybe aliasing..). And two-sided relatively small spurs are 100MHz component which is own sinusoidal term of original PSD.

[image]

Could the deterministic component of process (i.e. sinusoidal component) affect in form of spurs?

Comment: Hi David, and welcome to SP.SE! I've edited your question to be better read-able using Latex format, please use the Code Sample ("{}") in the editor to convert your code screenshot into copy-paste-able code!

Comment: Thank you Jdip! I've edited my code into copy-phase-able code.

Comment: You're right, there shouldn't be any aliasing. How are you computing the PSD? can you share that part of your code?

Comment: I've edited my question to share all of my code.

Comment: Actually, in my set-up, the array `phase` refers the timing jitter in [sec]. So my code is plotting the PSD of jitter[rad].

Comment: I used your code, WSS random process and parameters to re-create. I'm not seeing the issue, apart from the wrong scaling of the PSD

Comment: Did you see that two PSDs are identical? I observed the level-difference between two PSDs when I use the numpy-created WSS process, not phase noise.

Comment: And could you share how do you think about wrong scaling of the PSD? I added my results to original question..